# Python Email Validation - Time Out Error - File Handling Issue

Tags: python, validation, python-2.7, python-3.x, email-validation

I am using python module ( validate_email ).

```
from validate_email import validate_email

result=open('output.tsv','w')

f=open('input.csv','r')

y=[]

result.write('Email_address\tEmail_validation\n')

for i in f:
    y.append(i.replace('\n',''))

for j in range(len(y)):
    val=validate_email('%s'%y[j], verify=True)
    result.write('%s\t%s\n'%(y[j],val))
    print y[j],val
```

In that the input.csv file contains the list of email Id's to check.

After the for loop the result will be written in output file.

Problems:

1. Some time the script raise the Time out error `raise TimeoutError, 'Timeout'`

My input file contains 300 email Id's.

2. The output file was writing only the results of 120 emails. but on that time the program is still running upto 300 requests ( emails).

Comment: You will need to raise the issue with the module maintainer. I believe there is already an open issue: https://github.com/syrusakbary/validate_email/issues/9 (if this is the same module).

Comment: yes, Exactly the same. Please tell I have lot of email address to check, which method is good for that.

Comment: Send email, request reply, look for bounces.

Comment: To Avoid the time out Error I used try catch. But while writing into output file I writes only 125 lines. Remaining lines are processed in terminal but that was not writes in file

Answer (score 0):

As an more optimized way instead of `range(len(y))` you can just use `y` in your `for` loop :
because that every indexing or `len` has `O(n)` order and you are using **`3`** indexing in the loop also you have  `len(y)` too . Just use `in` operation :

```
for j in y:
    val=validate_email('%s'%j, verify=True)
    result.write('%s\t%s\n'%(j,val))
    print j,val
```

Comment: Yes, Thanks I understand. But after 15 counts it show time out error. Is there any other way to find the Email existance'

Comment: I have to check the lot email Id's to send a Newsletter.

Comment: maybe its because of `validate_email` ! i dont deal with it before , so i have not any idea !about it